# How do I customise the new user welcome email

Tags: email, user-registration

How can I customise the the new user welcome email ?

I tried 'http://www.sean-barton.co.uk/wordpress-welcome-email-editor/' however it conflicts with some of the other plugins I need to use, Cimy Extra Fields.

There is one other plugin that is to old for wordpress 3.0.1.

Will

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SB Welcome Email Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/welcome-email-editor/) works by replacing [`wp_new_user_notification()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification) with an own version. The original version can be found in [`wp-includes/pluggable.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1184), the plugin uses [an elaborate replacement with all kinds of options](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/welcome-email-editor/trunk/sb_welcome_email_editor.php?rev=269474#L57). You can do this to: create a new plugin (just a PHP file in `wp-content/plugins/`), and define `wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass = '')` there. This will then be used instead of the regular WordPress version.

Comment: This probably answers the question, however I solved the problem by using 'Register Plus Redux'. This is a much better plugin that better solved my plugins woes. It replaced 3 other plugins and did a better job.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/register-plus-redux/

Comment: I'm actually working to do the same thing as OP, but not really looking something as bloated as the plugin he ended up with. I looked into pluggable.php -> `wp_new_user_notification()`, but that doesn't appear to be the "new user welcome email" at all. Its for the email sent to the site admin that a new user has registered.

Comment: @ZachL: `wp_new_user_notification()` does both: it first sends the mail to the admin, then to the user.

Comment: @ZachL : be carefull on using the wp_new_user_notification() the codex says Note: If password is not passed to function, the newly registered user will not receive their welcome email.