# How to edit the Wordpress e-mail that gives the user their password?

Tags: email

Can't find the answer in the codex or on here. Just need to know what file to look in to find the e-mail template. The default e-mail that gets sent upon new user registration has a link which points to wp-admin, and I need it to point to frontend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at this question?

[How do I customise the new user welcome email](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4514/how-do-i-customise-the-new-user-welcome-email)